# Unity: How do I change the material of a prefab when it is not in the hierarchy?

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality

I am building an AR app using AR Foundation but got stuck with changing the material of my model during runtime by pressing a button.

The script below works perfectly fine when I attach it to my model and then create buttons with OnClick() Events to access the specific material WHEN my model is in the hierarchy.

But I don't want it to stay in the hierarchy because otherwise it will constantly show up in AR. If I remove it from the hierarchy, the OnClick() is obviously missing a prefab.

So I need to have the possibility to still change materials from button clicks but without my model staying in the hierarchy. I think "AddListener" could be a solution, but I don't really know how to edit the script in order to make it work. With AddListener I wouldn't have to use OnClick().

Can anyone please show me the solution?

```
using System.Collections;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using UnityEngine;
 
 
 public class ChangeColor : MonoBehaviour
 {
    
 public Material[] material;
 Material setMaterial;
 Renderer rend;
 
 void Start()
 {
     rend = GetComponent<Renderer>();
     rend.enabled=true;
 }
 
 void Update()
 {
 
 }
 
 public void GreyMaterial()
 {
    rend.sharedMaterial = material[0];
    setMaterial = rend.material;
 }
 
 public void YellowMaterial()
 {
     rend.sharedMaterial = material[1];
     setMaterial = rend.material;
 }
 
 public void RedMaterial()
 {
     rend.sharedMaterial = material[2];
     setMaterial = rend.material;
 }
 
 }
```

Comment: Why do you use so many functions to change the color, if you can use one with parameter - color

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I am new to programming and will look into it

Comment: When I was new to Unity, I made simple 2d games, not AR. Are you sure that you are able to make it? Well, you can make function like changeColor(string colorName) and then choose color with name: `if (colorName == "red") rend.sharedMaterial = material[1]; else if (colorName == "blue") rend.sharedMaterial = material[2];`  OR you can use function changeColor(int colorIndex). And just write `rend.sharedMaterial = material[colorIndex];` Here you must only set required parameter - number of color in array material

Comment: And also it hurts, no  DESTROYS, RUINS eyes of all programmers when you call the array `metarial'.  Because it is single. Call it materialS or game_materialS or something like that. There are rulesfor writing code. It is like etiquette. And you should write you code by the rules so that other programmers could read it and understand

Comment: thanks a lot! Always glad to receive some tips! :) i have to learn a lot. The app is almost finished and looks pretty sick but I got stuck with changing materials through the "place on plane" script from ar foundation. i am also working with 11 3d models with several colors and so far so your advice is great! would have a bunch of functions otherwise... i am working on this app for about 3 weeks now and definitely see how much you can learn by sticking to one project

Comment: Did my answer (not comment) help you?

Answer (score 0):

You can out your prefab in folder called "Resources". And get your prefab using [Resources.Load](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Resources.Load.html) in script next way:

```
GameObject prefab = Resources.Load<GameObject>("Path"); // Path WITHOUT "Resources/"
```

Here prefab is... your prefab and you get change some components and values in it.

P.S.

1. It is very important to write Resources letter to letter without mistakes
2. You may put folders into (folders into folders...) into Resources, but here you must set the exact path to your file.

Comment: I think the problem lies somewhere else. a couple of hours ago i tried different combinations. I combined the script above with my "place on plane" script, I also tried to make prefabs out of those buttons so I can attach them to my model. everything seems to be set up correctly. the script is attached to the model, the model is attached to the buttons as well as the functions through "OnClick()" but it still wont change the color in AR. when I do the same while having the model in hierarchy, everything is working. i think it has something to do with the way the "place on plane" script works

Comment: Do I understand correclty that your button is in hierarchy and when you click it the prefab meterial must be changed? And have you  already tried my way when you "tried different combinations"?

Comment: yes, you are right. I tried your solution twice now but it sadly still wont work.

Comment: i inserted the following code within void start()  of the code above --> GameObject StuhlSunset = Resources.Load<GameObject>("Assets/Models/StuhlSunset.prefab"); // Path WITHOUT "Resources/" is there anything i do wrong again?

Comment: Yes, there is. The object must be places in folder called Resources that must pe placedd of course in Assets. And you get the path: Assets/Resources/Models/StuhlSunset" But you shouldn't write "Assets/Resources". And you also souldn't write the extension .prefab (but here I am not sure, but I think you shouldn't). So put folder Models into Resources and write `GameObject StuhlSunset = Resources.Load<GameObject>("Models/StuhlSunset")`. If it still doesn't work try: `GameObject StuhlSunset = Resources.Load<>("Models/StuhlSunset") as GameObject`

Comment: sorry, don't even know why i didnt create the "Resources" folder... i tried it now and unfortunately still no success... your section code with "as GameObject" gives me the following error: Using the generic method group 'Load' requires 1 type arguments

Comment: Oh my god... Check if your prefab is actually named StuhlSunset. Or try to delete `<>` in here: `GameObject StuhlSunset = Resources.Load<GameObject>("Models/StuhlSunset")`

Comment: If still no success I do not know the reason

Comment: checked everything several times, but no success. this is what the console shows when i press the button in the simulator: UnassignedReferenceException: The variable rend of ChangeColor has not been assigned.
You probably need to assign the rend variable of the ChangeColor script in the inspector.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219509/discussion-between---and-raspberry).

Answer (score 0):

I believe the script is not referencing all the new instantiated objects, its needs to reference them. Either store those new objects in a list that the script can change, or try to search for every item of that material you want to change when you run the change material function(not very efficient, but might be easier)
i found this on youtube